# Brakeman unprotected redirect for Rails, S3, Paperclip

Tags: redirect, protected, brakeman

I'm getting this warning from Brakeman. As they say,redirects which rely on user-supplied values can be used to “spoof” websites or hide malicious links in otherwise harmless-looking URLs. They can also allow access to restricted areas of a site if the destination is not validated.

`| Confidence | Class               | Method   | Warning Type | Message
| High       | DocumentsController | download | Redirect     | Possible unprotected redirect near line 46: redirect_to(+Document.find(params[:id]).f`

In my controller I created a method `download` that takes the file URL (file stored on Amazon S3 and the URL in my database thanks to Paperclip) and creates a URL (ie. `document_url`) that will last 3 seconds (for the user to download) thanks to `.expiring_url(3)`

```
def download
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  document_url = @document.file.expiring_url(3)
  if URI.parse(document_url).host.include? "domain.com"
    redirect_to document_url, only_path: true
  else
    document_url = nil
  end
end
```

I have been trying pass Brakeman's validation without success. As you can see above, I tried to check if the my domain is present in the URL but it did not change the report on Brakeman.

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. I passed the warning by utilizing strong parameters like below, though I'm not sure why it works.

```
redirect_to referer_param

def referer_param
  params.require(:referer)
end
```